# How can I populate the following objects in multiple input fields?

Tags: javascript

Please forgive me if the title is not very descriptive,
I'm using vibrant.js to get a picture's color HEX, everything is working as expected and i'm quite happy with everything so far,please help me / guide me on how to get the values in the input text fields, MUCH APPRECIATED!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/dist/Vibrant.js"></script>

   
</head>
<body>
    
    
How to get the console result in the input fields below?
</br>
<label>1st<label>
<input value="" id="1"></br>
<p></p>
<label>2nd<label>
<input value="" id="2"></br>
<p></p>
<label>3rd<label>
<input value="" id="3"></br>
<p></p>
<label>4th<label>
<input value="" id="4"></br>
<p></p>
<label>5th<label>
<input value="" id="5"></br>
 
    
        <div class="row examples">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img data-src="examples/3.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           
<script>

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'examples/octocat.png')

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch])
            console.log(swatch, swatches[swatch].getHex())

    /*
     * Results into:
     * Vibrant #7a4426
     * Muted #7b9eae
     * DarkVibrant #348945
     * DarkMuted #141414
     * LightVibrant #f3ccb4
     */
});

</script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

My console perfectly returns

```
 * Vibrant #7a4426
 * Muted #7b9eae
 * DarkVibrant #348945
 * DarkMuted #141414
 * LightVibrant #f3ccb4
```

The main goal is to get the Color HEX into the input text field ( you can remove the color name bu removing (swatch,) in the console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example I made. Hopefully it helps!

```js
var url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465188035480-cf3a60801ea5?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=568&h=568&q=60&cs=tinysrgb&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D';
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', url + '&' + new Date().getTime());
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');

img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(img);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    var i = 0;
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
          document.getElementById(""+(i+1)).value = swatches[swatch].getHex();
          i = i + 1;
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/dist/Vibrant.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Vibrant</label>
      <input value="" class="form-control" id="1">
      <label>Muted</label>
      <input value="" class="form-control" id="2">
      <label>DarkVibrant</label>
      <input value="" class="form-control" id="3">
      <label>DarkMuted</label>
      <input value="" class="form-control" id="4">
      <label>LightVibrant</label>
      <input value="" class="form-control" id="5">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465188035480-cf3a60801ea5?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=568&h=568&q=60&cs=tinysrgb&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can find it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bgmpow5q/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following

```
for (var i=0; i< swatches.length; i++)
     if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatches[i]) && swatches[i]){
          document.getElementById(""+(i+1)).value = swatches[i].getHex();
          console.log(swatches[i], swatches[i].getHex())
        }
```

Comment: Hi Omar, thank you very much for taking your time to help me out -- could you please use the code snippet to test your code.. i followed your method with no success, thanks again

Comment: Hi, my console is empty and the value did not populate into the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking this approach (different for loop from yours) because I need to capture the input box;

luckily you have it as 1,2,3,4,5;

so I am using the index in interation; this index-in-iteration is difficult in a for-in structure;

hope this helps u.

```
for(i=1;i<=swatches.length;i++) {
    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) let hexValue =  swatches[swatch].getHex();
    if (hexValue != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(i).value = hexValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, thank you for your help, i really appreciate it, however i had no luck with your solution, could you please test it? many thanks

Comment: I dont have vibrant; but i can test my code if u can give me the "swatches" object;

Comment: No, I dont need vibrant js; just the "swatches" object , which we are iterating.

Comment: Here we go : var swatches = vibrant.swatches()

Comment: Vibrant.prototype.swatches = function() {
      return {
        LogoVibrant: this.VibrantSwatch,
        LogoMuted: this.MutedSwatch,
        LogoDarkVibrant: this.DarkVibrantSwatch,
        LogoDarkMuted: this.DarkMutedSwatch,
        LogoLightVibrant: this.LightVibrantSwatch,
        LightMuted: this.LightMuted
      };

    };

Comment: I tried compiling your html as such and got into a weird error; I am not interested in learning vibrant , but I want to help you; but I think I wasnt very clear; In your code there is a line 

var swatches = vibrant.swatches();

Can  u please do 
      console.log(swatches) in your code and give me the answer;

That way i can fix my code quick